# Documentation for Web API with conventional routing

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I just tried to use Swagger with an ASP.Net Core Web API project, but it did not find any of my controllers / actions. Turns out Swagger does not support conventional routing (as stated here https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore). All my routes are generated in code inside one function, using routeBuilder.MapRoute(). I have 150 controllers and ~500 actions - applying attribute routing to this project will be a nightmare!

It seems there's no way to make Swagger work with conventional routing. Are there any alternatives to Swagger that do?